# Unable to use Custom domain purchased thru Azure with App Service

Tags: azure, dns, cname, paas, custom-domain

I recently purchased a new custom domain to use with my App Service. I have done this before without any problems but cannot get this setup.  I have tried to set this up via two methods:

1) Add hostname binding within the Custom Domain blade. This fails with an error with no extra details.

[Add hostname bindings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/06bPF.png)

2) Add custom domain within the App Service blade

[Configure custom domains](https://i.stack.imgur.com/plROQ.png)

This fails on domain ownership and ask me to create a CNAME configuration record.

[Add CNAME error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zj0Cf.png)

I assume this is also why option 1) fails silently.
 
I have tried this by entering the Advanced Management Portal on the Custom Domain blade but this does not give me access to add any DNS records, all I can do it edit the Nameservers.

Help !!!!  This means I am left with a domain I purchased that I cannot use and I cannot no longer buy this through an external provider so I can setup it up externally from Azure.

Comment: 1) Edit your question and put the pictures inline to the question so that we don't need to click links. 2) None of your links show an actual error. 3) Where did you purchase your domain? All registrars have the ability to add DNS resource records.  Read the registrars' FAQ.

Comment: I purchased the domain from within Azure using Buy domain option under Custom Domains. I realize this is a mistake but have done it now. I have done it previously without problems. Since i bought this through Azure I do not have anything from the registrar I can access. I am not even sure who the registrar is. I know is used to be  GoDaddy? I can access a setting page via the Advanced Management Portal on the Custom Domain blade (which should be registrars) but this only allows me to change the nameservers, not add any DNS records.

Comment: When I try to add hostname custom binding all i get is an error saying failed to add acme.com to acme app service. No error or explanation why.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the custom domain so Azure manages the DNS. It can then add the appropriate DNS records when you add bindings.